# BCC in mail Function

Tags: php, bcc

Hi i am trying to add BCC to mail function but it does not works. can anybody please help???
 Here my code.

```
<?php 
     if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
     $cleanedFrom = $_POST['mailtxt'];
      $to ='abcd@abc.com'; 
        $subject = 'Booking Form';
        $headers = "From: " . $cleanedFrom . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $message= '<html><body>';
        $message .= "</table>";
        $message .= "</body></html>";
        $headers .=  "BCC: abc@abc.com;\r\n";
        $send =    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        $send =    mail ("info@visitkullumanali.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
    if($send)
    {
        echo "<script> window.location = 'wwww.mysite.com' </script>";}
    else
    {
        echo "<script> window.location = 'index.html' </script>";
    }
 }
```

?>

Comment: You'd probably be better off using [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) that was designed for this kind of thing.

Comment: Have you tried `$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";` no semicolon after address...etc? This is a copy from the manual

Comment: thanks for response i am trying the same

Comment: BTW. This program is open for email-injection, because you use the posted value directly in your email header. Do something like: `if ( preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $cleanedFrom )) die('injection detected');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: abc@abc.com' . "\r\n";
```

[REFERENCE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: please check in answers i have put my all code but still this is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
    $headers .=  "BCC: abc@abc.com;\r\n";
```

Remove that extra `;` from `Bcc` value

```
    $headers .=  "Bcc: abc@abc.com\r\n";
```

Comment: Your code which you posted as an answer still has the same issue. That is why it is not working. Remove that `;` after the email address

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an important point:

If you want BCC add the receiver via "To:" but not to the headers. People only see who also got the mail via the header information. So you are good to go by adding it via "To:"